5/8" T1-11 for garage ceiling
I built a new, high-bay garage with trusses set at 2' OC. I would like to use 5/8" T1-11 wood-based siding for the ceiling, but am concerned that the T1-11 will sag between trusses over time. Thoughts, comments, recommendations?

I added a web-searched explanation of "T1-11". At first it sounded like either a form of fluorescent lighting or a droid from Star Wars. An explanation of codes and abbreviations will help folks who try to answer your questions. If "T1-11" doesn't mean siding to you, please edit to explain what you mean by it.

Have you checked your local authorities regarding requirements of non-combustible materials in garage wall coverings?

@Triplefault T1-11 is a common type of manufactured wood material that acts both as sheathing and siding, that is, you don't need to use 1/2" sheathing, then add siding over that. It's common in sheds and other outdoor buildings. Now, as far as I know, it's not fire retardant and can't be used in garages, but it all depends on OP's location.

@Cheery Thanks for the info! When I web-searched it, I recognized it as the stuff the house I grew up in was sided with. I never knew it had a special designation.

You could apply the T1-11 siding panels long ways across the trusses (the long dimension perpendicular with the trusses rather than parallel with them as is usual. Since the grooves formed into the panels will not be parallel with the trusses there will be less chance of sagging.
Alternatively, you could add some cross-pieces between the trusses every couple feet and attach the panels to the cross-pieces as well as the trusses, which would reduce sag.

T1-11 also comes as OSB.

The answer also mentions rafters, but the OP says they have trusses.
